# Why is my java build failing using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, build

I'm getting this error when trying to compile a java project.

```
[INFO] Failed to parse a schema.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:46 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-10T11:37:54+10:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc (demo) on project demo-server: Could not process schema files in directory C:\Users\jake\Desktop\Demos\ec\server\src\main\xsd\demo -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

I'm not too sure what's going wrong here, or how to fix it in order to make it successfully build.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are from the "xjc" task of "jaxb2-maven-plugin".  It is trying to generate Java source code from XSD files in the "src\main\xsd\demo" directory.

Apparently, there is a syntax problem in one or more of the XSD files.

To get more information about those syntax problems, try running Maven in debug mode; e.g. include the `-X` option on the `mvn` command line.